# Ruby name of Module from a class defined within

Tags: ruby

I have ruby code like this:

```
module Hello

  class Hi

    def initialize()
      puts self.module.name //Should print "Hello"
    end

  end
end
```

How can I get the name of the module the class is included in?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [Module::nesting](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-c-nesting) method:

> **nesting** → array
>
> Returns the list of Modules nested at the point of call.

```
module M
  class C
    Module.nesting[1] # => M
  end
end
```

If you want to get this value from the instance methods, you can assign it to class variable:

```
module Hello    
  class Hi
    @@parent = Module.nesting[1]

    def initialize()
      puts @@parent # => Hello
    end
  end
end
```