# Getting module a class is defined in without string manipulation

Tags: ruby

Referencing ( [Ruby name of Module from a class defined within](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990368/), [Module.nesting within instance_eval/exec or module_eval/exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337821/))

In the following setup:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end
```

Is there are way to get the module name `Foo` without having to modify `Bar` and without resorting to string manipulation on the fully-qualified name `Foo::Bar`?

Comment: What's wrong with a tiny bit of string manipulation, or are you just curious if it is possible?

Comment: If there is a string, it must be generated from some sort of metadata, and I'd rather work on the data itself than on the string as this might prevent edge cases from coming up. Not saying that string manipulation is bad. And yes, also curiousity.

Comment: I suppose you could write a quick C extension that's the same as `Module.nesting` without the `NODE_FL_CREF_PUSHED_BY_EVAL` checks. I'm not sure what sort of pitfalls you'd run into though.

Comment: I think that would be out of scope for what I'm doing. In that case I'll settle for string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm cheating, I don't modify `Bar` but `Class`:

```
class Class
  def my_module
    self.to_s.split('::').first
  end
end 

module Foo
  class Bar    
  end
end

p Foo::Bar.my_module  #-> "Foo"

#Works also after include
include Foo
p Bar.my_module #-> "Foo"
```

Comment: Wouldn't handle multiple, nested modules and I could easily just operate on `Foo::Bar.name`.